# konzipieren vs. konzeptionieren vs. konzeptualisieren

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference in the meaning of the verbs "konzipieren", "konzeptionieren" and "konzeptualisieren"? There are a few forum posts and "konzeptionieren" is probably not in the Duden, even if I have read it more often.

Was ist der Unterschied in der Bedeutung der Verben "konzipieren", "konzeptionieren" und "konzeptualisieren"? Es gibt ein paar Foreneinträge und "konzeptionieren" steht wohl nicht im Duden, auch wenn ich es schon öfter gelesen habe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are not big, and lie more in the domain of use than in the actual semantics:

1. **konzipieren** means *ein Konzept machen*, so *to create a concept*, as in *to make a draft, a plan, a sketch*.
2. **konzeptionieren** means *eine Konzeption machen*. So, for knowing the difference between *konzipieren* and *konzeptionieren*, we need to know the difference between *Konzept* and *Konzeption*. The difference is more in the domain of use, I would say. Both *Konzeption* and *Konzept* mean *draft, plan, sketch*. Konzeption seems to be the standard term used at least in [advertisment](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konzepter) and [social pedagogics](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konzeption_(Sozialp%C3%A4dagogik)). Maybe there are other areas, where *Konzeption* is preferred over *Konzept*, and thus *konzeptionieren* over *konzipieren* (Just as a side note: One difference is, that *Konzeption* has the medical meaning of *conception*, which *Konzept* does not have, but this is not relevant here.)
3. **konzeptualisieren** is more different. Although it also means *ein Konzept machen* (*make a concept*), *Konzept* (*concept*) has a different meaning here and refers to a *mental representation*. The term *konzeptualisieren* is used in cognitive sciences to describe the mental process of *conceptualizing*, i.e. the processes in the brain which lead to the mental representation of *structured, ordered entities* from data which are thought of to be *unordered* (or ordered differently). For instance recognizing a pattern of color dots on a printout as a *child* could also be called *conceptualizing* the dots as a child, and you would use *konzeptualisieren* for this. This notion of *konzeptualisieren* is taken from cognitive sciences and going into linguistics and rhetorics and social sciences where the english term for it is *framing*. *konzeptualisieren* has very much the same meaning as the english word [*conceptualize*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceptualize) from which *konzeptualisieren* is [loaned into german](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/konzeptualisieren) One example could be the sentence

> Es ergibt Sinn, die Erfindung der Dampfmaschine, der Eisenbahn und des automatischen Webstuhls als Revolution zu konzeptualisieren. 
>   (It makes sense to conceptualize the invention of the  steam-engine, the railway and the automatic loom as a revolution)

Comment: Spot on! That's a very good conceptualization of concept and conception! Now the question: what do you think of contraceptives?